# How to get Referrals URL, Landed on my site from Google Ads

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I am struggling to get Referrals URL.

Actually , i have a Adwords Campaign and my Ads is showing on Google Ads Display partner site using Google Ads Program.
After Click on Ads,  person landed on mypage. now on my landed page on my side i want to get the url, person was on right before they landed on my page,  means on which url ads was showing..
I want to get referrals url using GA API.

https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2382957?hl=en

They say using GA it is possible.

Is this possible to get URL with GA ?

If yes then what is the search criteria to get Referral url landed from Google Ads.

Which one report could help me for this report ?

I will use GA API PHP version.

Thank You

Naresh Kumar